# Apache pig query to join two schemas

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

For example,

```
  relation1: {a: chararray, b: chararray}
  (1, abc)
  (2, asd)
  relation2: {a: chararray, c: chararray}
  (1, 2.5)
  (2, 4.0)
```

The question is:
Is it possible to get a resultant relation with schema as below:
For example: **number of tuples in realtion1 is 2 and number of tuples in relation2 is 2. The number of tuples in resultant relation should also be 2 only.**

```
  relation3: {a: chararray, b: chararray, c: chararray}
  (1, abc, 2.5)
  (2, asd, 4.0)
```

Could any one help to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

```
joined = JOIN relation1 BY a, relation2 BY a;
describe joined;
-- joined: {relation1::a: chararray,relation1::b: chararray,relation2::a: chararray,relation2::c: chararray}
relation3 = FOREACH joined GENERATE relation1::a AS a, b, c;
describe relation3;
-- relation3: {a: chararray, b: chararray, c: chararray}
```

The '::' is called the [disambugate operator](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/basic.html#disambiguate) and used to deconflict schemas after certain operations (such as a join). After a join all of the values from each alias are still present and you can pull them out using a FOREACH.

Comment: relation1 and relation2 had 5492 tuples. After executing, the schema of relation3 is relation3: {a: chararray,relation1::b: chararray,relation2::c: chararray} which is not as you mentioned and the number of tuples in relation3 is 769213 (which is not expected. Expected count is 5492-same as relation1 and relation2). I got the same schema of joined relation as you have mentioned.  May I know what is wrong?